# Extract uppercase rows and fill down until next uppercase row

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I have some data which looks like:

```
   RegionName
   <chr>     
 1 ANDALUCÍA 
 2 Almería   
 3 Abla      
 4 Abrucena  
 5 Adra      
 6 ALBÁNCHEZ 
 7 Alboloduy 
 8 Albox     
 9 ALCOLEA   
10 Alcóntar
```

Where some of the columns are `uppercase`. I want to extract the uppercase columns into a new column and `fill(down)` until the next uppercase column.

Expected output:

```
   RegionName REGIONNAME
   <chr>        <chr>
 1 ANDALUCÍA   ANDALUCÍA   -first result
 2 Almería     ANDALUCÍA
 3 Abla        ANDALUCÍA
 4 Abrucena    ANDALUCÍA
 5 Adra        ANDALUCÍA
 6 ALBÁNCHEZ   ALBÁNCHEZ  - change here
 7 Alboloduy   ALBÁNCHEZ
 8 Albox       ALBÁNCHEZ
 9 ALCOLEA     ALCOLEA    - change here
10 Alcóntar    ALCOLEA
```

Data:

```
data = structure(list(RegionName = c("ANDALUCÍA", "Almería", "Abla", 
"Abrucena", "Adra", "ALBÁNCHEZ", "Alboloduy", "Albox", "ALCOLEA", 
"Alcóntar")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the regions together based on if their name is `==` to their name in all upper case. Then set all names within the group to the `first` `RegionName` which is in all caps.

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(RegionName == toupper(RegionName))) %>%
  mutate(REGIONNAME = first(RegionName))
```

**Output**

```
   RegionName   grp REGIONNAME
   <chr>      <int> <chr>     
 1 ANDALUCÍA      1 ANDALUCÍA 
 2 Almería        1 ANDALUCÍA 
 3 Abla           1 ANDALUCÍA 
 4 Abrucena       1 ANDALUCÍA 
 5 Adra           1 ANDALUCÍA 
 6 ALBÁNCHEZ      2 ALBÁNCHEZ 
 7 Alboloduy      2 ALBÁNCHEZ 
 8 Albox          2 ALBÁNCHEZ 
 9 ALCOLEA        3 ALCOLEA   
10 Alcóntar       3 ALCOLEA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(RegionName = c("ANDALUCÍA", "Almería", "Abla", 
"Abrucena", "Adra", "ALBÁNCHEZ", "Alboloduy", "Albox", "ALCOLEA", 
"Alcóntar")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 2):

An idea is to use `grepl()` to recognise the `[[:upper:]]`, convert the others to NA and `fill()`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
 mutate(new = replace(RegionName, !grepl("^[[:upper:]]+$", RegionName), NA)) %>% 
 fill(new)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   RegionName new      
   <chr>      <chr>    
 1 ANDALUCÍA  ANDALUCÍA
 2 Almería    ANDALUCÍA
 3 Abla       ANDALUCÍA
 4 Abrucena   ANDALUCÍA
 5 Adra       ANDALUCÍA
 6 ALBÁNCHEZ  ALBÁNCHEZ
 7 Alboloduy  ALBÁNCHEZ
 8 Albox      ALBÁNCHEZ
 9 ALCOLEA    ALCOLEA  
10 Alcóntar   ALCOLEA
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `ifelse` and `fill`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(REGIONNAME = ifelse(RegionName == toupper(RegionName), RegionName, NA)) %>% 
  fill(REGIONNAME)

   RegionName REGIONNAME
1   ANDALUCÍA  ANDALUCÍA
2     Almería  ANDALUCÍA
3        Abla  ANDALUCÍA
4    Abrucena  ANDALUCÍA
5        Adra  ANDALUCÍA
6   ALBÁNCHEZ  ALBÁNCHEZ
7   Alboloduy  ALBÁNCHEZ
8       Albox  ALBÁNCHEZ
9     ALCOLEA    ALCOLEA
10   Alcóntar    ALCOLEA
```